# Chunk file stream and send them to azure blob by asp.net core

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

can somebody help me with problem that happen when i'm trying to send large file(256mb~) to azure blob. Error is OutofMemoryException. App is hosting in webApp on azure with 3.5gb ram plan.
Schema of transfering looks like:
-sending file from here

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="UploadFiles" asp-action="Post" style="margin-top: 100px;">
<div>
    <p>Upload one or more files using this form:</p>
    <input type="file" name="files" multiple />
</div>
<div>
    <p>Your Username</p>
    <input type="text" name="username" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</div>
```

controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("");
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("testcontainer");
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");
    FormValueProvider formModel;

    formModel = await Request.StreamFile(storageAccount);
```

-stream file extension i took from example in microsoftdocs, inside it i put method that chunk memory stream on blockblob and send them as BlockList

```
var formAccumulator = new KeyValueAccumulator();
string targetFilePath = null;

var boundary = MultipartRequestHelper.GetBoundary(
    MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(request.ContentType),
    DefaultFormOptions.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit);
var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, request.Body);

var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
while (section != null)
{
    ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition;
    var hasContentDispositionHeader = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(section.ContentDisposition, out contentDisposition);

    if (hasContentDispositionHeader)
    {
        if (MultipartRequestHelper.HasFileContentDisposition(contentDisposition))
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await section.Body.CopyToAsync(stream);
                stream.Position = 0;

                await new AzureBlobUtil().UploadBlob(stream, blockBlob, "testcontainer", "testBlob");
            }
```

i think problem is in memory stream, cause there storing whole file before sending to azure, but i dont know how to chunk it. I mean idk how to send part of MultipartReader.

Comment: Why don't you just use `await new AzureBlobUtil().UploadBlob(section.Body, blockBlob, "testcontainer", "testBlob");`? I don't see the point of copying to a MemoryStream. Also, please post the implementation of `UploadBlob`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, thanks a lot. I changed my part that sending stream to azure like this.
`await new AzureBlobUtil().UploadBlob(section.Body, blobAccount, "testcontainer", "testBlob");`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, UploadBlob:
https://pastebin.com/P7qT6Fis

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, but now UploadBlob doesnt working, so i changed to :
`await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(section.Body);`
But now i still cant upload file ~500mb.